# parameterized at TestClass level in JUnit?

Tags: junit

I have a set of tests cases in a single JUnit class, say test1() and test2(). 
Example:

```
class Template
{
    test1()
    test2()
}
```

I want to execute my set of tests(test class) over the elements in a list. For example, let's say I had a list of table names  (e.g., table1, table2, ...), and I want to execute my set of tests over each table name.

Need test results as follow,

```
table1
    test1_result
    test2_result
table2
    test1_result
    test2_result
```

I have searched, found 'Parameterized test cases' but this is parameterized at test case level, but i need parameterized at Test class level. is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused about `Parameterized` or didn't describe your needs well. What you describe is what `Parameterized` does. For each input to your test class (each array returns from `Parameters`) every unit test in the class is run. So if you pass `table1` and `table2` to your class, `test1` and `test2` will each be run twice, once with `table1` and once with `table2`.

If this is not what you are looking for, please describe the difference between `Parameterized` and what you are looking for better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i tried as you specified, but problem is test case report are generated under Template class(test case reports are generated using ant junitreport), is it possible generate separate test case results for table1 and table2

Comment: Not familiar with this. Seems like you need to post a new question specifically about generating reports using junitreport.